# "We must eat to live, not live to eat." — What kind of rhetorical figure is that?

Tags: word-choice, rhetoric

In this kind of sentence the second half is an inversion of the first half. Is it a rhetorical artífice? What kind?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a type of *chiasmus* (in general) or *antimetabole* (to be specific).

Example of *antimetabole* from [Sylvae Rhetoricae](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/):

> You can take the gorilla out of the jungle, but you can't take the jungle out of the gorilla.

Comment: It is indeed the exact term for OP's example. But does it include, say, [*"In Soviet Russia, you rob bank. In Capitalist America, bank robs **you!**"*](http://memegenerator.net/In-Soviet-Russia) ?