# Aphorisms that use two words in reverse order

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, figures-of-speech, aphorism

I've found aphorisms often that play on the meaning of two words and their interaction and was wondering **what one might call them**.

An example is the PJ Harvey song name:

> The whore hustles and the hustler whores.

They are quite simple but interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really not *epanodos* (which is simply "Repeating the main terms of an argument in the course of presenting it"), it's really more like *antimetabole*:

> Repetition of words, in successive clauses, in reverse grammatical order.
>   This figure is sometimes known as chiasmus.

Read about these and other rhetorical figures on [Sylva Rhetoricae](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/).

See a similar question answered [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/199509/2303), among other places. (In fact, now that I look, this question appears to be a dupe of that.)

Answer (score 2):

They use a figure of speech called **[epanados](http://changingminds.org/techniques/language/figures_speech/epanados.htm)**

From changingminds.org:

> *Description*
>
> Epanados is the **repetition of words** from earlier in a phrase or
>   sentence **in the reverse order**.
>
> *Examples*
>
> - Love is right because there is only one right love.
> - A right is given, which gives you right.
> - Mad, bad and sad they say, but I'm just sad that such bad things are
>     said by those who can only be mad.